# How to render a matplotlib plot with hatch pattern to pdf with reportlab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab

I am unable to render correctly a matplotlib plot that contains hatch pattern to a pdf via reportlab.

Here is below a sample code that highlights the problem. The example is a simple but reportlab is needed in the project I am working on, so I cannot output straight to pdf from matplotlib.

```
from io import BytesIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.randint(50, 90, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, "o", color="b")
plt.axhspan(ymin=40, ymax=55, hatch="/", facecolor="none")
plt.show()

imgdata = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format="svg")
imgdata.seek(0)

drawing = svg2rlg(imgdata)
drawing.scale(0.5, 0.5)
c = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
renderPDF.draw(drawing, c, 10, 200)
c.drawString(100, 100, "No hatch pattern rendered")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

The expected plot output is (as it is from matplotlib):

[image]

however, when exporting to pdf, I'm getting:

[image]

The culprit here seems to be `svg2rlg` that does not the following from the svg output of matplotlib:

```
    Can't handle color: url(#h06c0184332)
```

Is there a way to circumvent this problem while keeping the output from matplotlib as svg?

Comment: Looks like it's a known limitation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571406/19261326